# Searching for specific word and returning specific lines

Tags: python, lambda, readlines

I got help with the code below but need to know how to get it to do it for all matches.

```
result = []
# 1. Search for the first failed entry:
with open('diskDetails.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if ': Failed' in line:
            result = lines[idx-3:idx+25]  # save lines from 'ID' to 'Sub Vendor'
            #break  # only the first match

# 2. Filter result:
keywords = ('ID', 'State', 'Capacity', 'Product ID', 'Serial No.')
result = list(filter(lambda l: str(l).startswith(keywords), result))

# 3. Save result:
with open('dataFinal.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.writelines(result)
```

So if I uncomment the 'break' it only shows the first (as stated) 
(output)

```
ID                              : 0:1:2
State                           : Failed
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Product ID                      : ST3600057SS
Serial No.                      : 6SL7YFWF
```

and if I comment out, it only shows a match after the first. 
(output)

```
ID                              : 0:1:5
State                           : Failed
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Product ID                      : ST3600057SS
Serial No.                      : 6SLAWWHQ
```

How can I get it to return all matches in the file (both outputs above)?

diskDetails.txt sample. The file may contain 4-8 sections like the below. I didn't include every line of each section (starting with ID) because each section is 28 lines long. Assume the keywords are in every section. Also each section is separated by a blank line (if that helps).

```
ID                              : 0:1:0
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:0
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:1
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:0
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:2
Status                          : Critical
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:2
State                           : Failed
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:3
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:3
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:4
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES64
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:5
Status                          : Non-Critical
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:5
State                           : Failed
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : Yes
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : Not Applicable
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)

ID                              : 0:1:6
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:6
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : 0
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
```

How to output and save only sections that contain 'Failed' and only include lines that include the keywords of each section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change #1: Appending results to the list. Before you were re-assigning on each loop

```
if ': Failed' in line:
    result.append(lines[idx-3:idx+25])
```

Change #2: Update our filter logic to loop over result since it is now a list of lists

```
results = list(filter(lambda l: str(l).startswith(keywords), r) for r in result)
```

Change #3: Loop over the results and write to file

```
with open('dataFinal.txt', 'wt') as f:
    for result in results:
        f.writelines(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you cullzie! I'll try and wrap my head around this better. It worked!

Comment: For anyone else reading, I commented out the 'break'. Thanks again cullzie, I couldn't find this exact scenario anywhere and I'm a newb. xD

Answer (score 1):

You created an empty list with the line "result = []", that is good.

You redefine the list "result" each pass through the for-loop with the line:
     result = lines[idx-3:idx+25]

You want to add to the list "result" in the for-loop with something like:
     result.append(lines[idx-3:idx+25])